# I am unable to change state with button with onsen-ui - please

Tags: onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I am learning Onsen-ui React and button to reset state is not working.

See below a simple test case

´´´

```
class MyApp extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { myVal: 123 };
}

clickTest() {
this.setState({ myVal:456 });
}

render() {
return (
<Page>
<div id="test">{this.state.myVal}</div>
<ons-button onClick="clickTest()">test</ons-button>
<ons-button onPress={() => { this.setState({ myVal:999}); }}>test</ons-button>
</Page>
);
}
}
```

```
My kidney for a good answer ;-) its bugging me for days

I want to change the state of myVal with ons-button and react
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code:

- Your constructor should bind `this` for the `clickTest` function: `this.clickTest = this.clickTest.bind(this);`
- The syntax for `onClick` is `onClick={this.clickTest}` not `onClick="clickTest()"`.
- `onPress` is not a valid `ons-button` prop; it should be `onClick`.

This is the fixed code:

```js
class MyApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { myVal: 123 };
    this.clickTest = this.clickTest.bind(this);
  }
  
  clickTest() {
    this.setState({ myVal:456 });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Page>
        <div id="test">{this.state.myVal}</div>
        <ons-button onClick={this.clickTest}>test</ons-button>
        <ons-button onClick={() => { this.setState({ myVal:999}); }}>test</ons-button>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

One kidney please.

##### Reference

- [Onsen UI playground](https://onsen.io/playground/?framework=react&category=getting%20started&module=using%20the%20components) where you can see examples and test your code in the browser
- [Onsen UI React Button documentation](https://onsen.io/v2/api/react/Button.html)
- [React events documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)